# Django 3.0.8 URL/Template/Routing Troubles "No reverse match"

Tags: python, django

first post so please forgive my ignorance as this is my first django app.

I am trying to create a template that displays all of the information regarding a specific "Ticket" from a list of all open tickets.

Unfortunately I am receiving following message whenever I attempt to add an anchor with a template url tag:

> NoReverseMatch at /tickets/tasks/ Reverse for 'order' with arguments
> '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['tickets/order/(?P<ticket_id>[^/]+)/$']

***Error message updated. Please see Update below.***

**And it is ONLY on this one HTML Template.**

Below is all of the code I believe will be able to shed some light into the issue:

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.



class Ticket(models.Model):
    """A basic support ticket"""
    # User ticket title. 
    ticket_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    # When the request was submitted.
    ticket_Submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    #Ticket Type
    ticketTypeChoices=[
        ('Update', 'Article Edit/Update'),
        ('Addition', 'New Content/Article Request'),
        ('Typo', 'Article Typo/Formatting Issue'),
        ('Issue', 'Website Error/Issue'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    ]

    # Type of ticket (Update, Addition, Typo, Site Issue)
    ticket_Type = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=ticketTypeChoices,
        default= 'Other'
    )
    # Users Name
    ticket_Contact = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # User Email (for follow up)
    ticket_Email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    # Article URL (if applicable)
    ticket_URL = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=254)
    # User description of the issue. 
    ticket_Description = models.TextField()
    
    #Ticket Status Choices
    StatusChoices = [
        ('Pending', 'Pending'),
        ('Open', 'Open'),
        ('Complete', 'Complete'),
        ('Deferred', 'Deferred'),
        ('Awaiting Response', 'Awaiting Response'),
    ]
    # Status of the Ticket 
    ticket_Status = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        choices=StatusChoices,
        default= 'Pending'
    )
    # Comments from HelpDesk Staff
    ticket_Comments = models.TextField(blank=True )

    #Shows when the ticket was last saved. 
    ticket_Last_Updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model"""
        return self.ticket_Name
```

**views.py:**

```
    # Imports Models from the app
    from  . models import *
    # Imports from the Forms List
    from . forms import TicketForm
    
    # Create your views here.
    
    # View of all active tickets
    def ticket(request):
        tickets = Ticket.objects.all().order_by('-ticket_Submitted')
        context = {'ticket': tickets}
        return render(request, 'tickets/joblist.html', context)
    
    # User can view details about a Ticket
    
    def order(request, ticket_id):
        order = Ticket.objects.get(id=ticket_id)
        context= {'order': order}
        return render(request, 'tickets/tix.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views


app_name='tickets'

urlpatterns = [

    # Include default auth urls.
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    # Support Ticket Form 
    path('submit/', views.submit, name='submit'),
    # Contact Us Form
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    # TicketWeblist
    path('tasks/', views.ticket, name='tasks'),
    # Ticket Details
    path('order/<str:ticket_id>/', views.order, name='order' )
   
]
```

**Template (joblist.html):**

```
{% for tickets in ticket %}
<tr>
    <td>{{tickets.ticket_Name}}</td>
    <td>{{tickets.ticket_Type}}</td>
    <td>{{tickets.ticket_Contact}}</td>
    <td>{{tickets.ticket_Status}}</td>
    <td>{{tickets.ticket_Submitted}}</td>
    <td>{{tickets.ticket_Last_Updated}}</td>
    <td><a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'tickets:order' ticket.id %}">View</a>
</tr>

{% endfor %}
```

After reviewing the code a dozen time, all I can be sure of is that is an issue that begins with the template anchor template url tag. (View) but no matter what format I try it comes up with this or a similar error.

UPDATE: At Mel's suggestion changed the url 'order' to 'tickets:order' and am now receiving the following message:

> NoReverseMatch at /tickets/tasks/ Reverse for 'order' with arguments
> '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ['tickets/order/(?P<ticket_id>[^/]+)/$']

I have been attempting to resolve this issue for about three days and was determined to solve it myself. Any type of help is appreciated and please feel free to point out any spaghetti code or lack of notes as well as I am looking for ways to grow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've set a namespace for your urls: `app_name = 'tickets'`

So correct reverse url would be.

```
{% url 'tickets:order' tickets.id %}
```

Can you try changing your `order` view function to this -

```
def order(request, ticket_id):
    active_order = Ticket.objects.get(id=ticket_id)
    context= {'order': active_order}
    return render(request, 'tickets/tix.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a separate `urls.py` for you app (it looks like it), so be sure to include `namespace = tickets` in your project `urls.py` file. And then in your template, you should do as follows:

```
{% url 'tickets:order' ticket.id %}
```

In other words, you need to include the name of the app as well.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I did as you suggested and had the following error return: 

NoReverseMatch at /tickets/tasks/

Reverse for 'order' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['tickets/order/(?P<ticket_id>[^/]+)/$']

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that you are passing ticket.id from your template to the view, however there is no ticket.id anywhere in the code. Why don't you try passing a value that is there in the template. It should work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Updated and fixed the typo on here. Unfortunately (or fortunately?) it ws right on my code.

Comment: @Merica_Man_Sam  i didnt see any ticket.id in the template or being passed from the view to the template. Since there is no value for ticket.id you are getting the error.

Comment: @Merica_Man_Sam the error you get is that there are no arguments being passed. If there were it would get routed to your path('order/<str:ticket_id>/', views.order, name='order' )

Comment: Thank you for your help Bijin! Your answer and Tabaene's help me realize my rookie mistake and help me get back on track!